# How to set fixed width column in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a gridLayout with three columns, how to set fixed width for middle column in percentage and others with auto width?

I tried this:

```
<GridLayout class="profiles" rows="auto, auto, auto" columns="*, 90%, *">
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: It will be much easy to help you if you provide the more complete example with your desired layout and point what exactly not layout as you want.

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: I don't think percentage width is supported in GridLayout columns, an alternative is to find the 90% width form it's container and assign it in absolute number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set fixed width for first column and for the second column, you can set 9 times to the third one.

```
<GridLayout columns="60, 9*, *" rows="*, *" height="230"
            backgroundColor="lightgray">
            <Label text="Label 1" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="red"></Label>
            <Label text="Label 2" row="0" col="1" backgroundColor="green"></Label>
            <Label text="Label 3" row="0" col="2" backgroundColor="blue"></Label>

            <Label text="Label 4" row="1" col="0" backgroundColor="yellow"></Label>
            <Label text="Label 5" row="1" col="1" backgroundColor="orange"></Label>
            <Label text="Label 6" row="1" col="2" backgroundColor="pink"></Label>

        </GridLayout>
```

I have created a playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=qDOull).